# make dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to create dataframe as below.
I tried to create it but there some several for loops and many code lines to do.
Is there any efficent way to create dataframe?

what I have:

```
x=array([a,b,c,d])
y=array([A,B,C,D])
id=array([1,2,3,4])
```

what I want to have:

```
df:
id   type   cat
1      a      x
2      b      x
3      c      x
4      d      x
1      A      y
2      B      y
3      C      y
4      D      y
```

Comment: IIUC you should be able to do `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'id:id, 'type':x, 'cat':'x'}), pd.DataFrame({'id:id, 'type':y, 'cat':'y'})])`

Answer (score 1):

```
x = np.array(["a","b","c","d"])
y = np.array(["A","B","C","D"])
id = np.array([1,2,3,4])
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'x': x, 'y':y})
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id'], value_vars=['x', 'y'], var_name='cat', value_name='type')
```

you can use pandas melt function to create your desired output dataframe.
Please refer this link [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) for more information on melt

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) and pass the 2 dataframes of interest constructed by making a dict with the desired column names and data as the keys, this will vertically stack the dataframes:

```
In[85]:
x=np.array(['a','b','c','d'])
y=np.array(['A','B','C','D'])
id=np.array([1,2,3,4])
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'id':id, 'type':x, 'cat':'x'}, columns=['id','type','cat']), pd.DataFrame({'id':id, 'type':y, 'cat':'y'}, columns=['id','type','cat'])])

Out[85]: 
   id type cat
0   1    a   x
1   2    b   x
2   3    c   x
3   4    d   x
0   1    A   y
1   2    B   y
2   3    C   y
3   4    D   y
```